# Center then left align image grid in Bootstrap fluid width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 with below requirements:

1. Each thumbnail image has fixed known width, let say 200px in this case. **There could be multiple columns** (if the screen is large, it could have 5-6 columns as needed).
2. This whole page must be fluid width
3. The container (`.center` in this case) must be center of the **page**
4. Then within the container (`.grid` in this case), the thumbnails themselves must be left aligned. For example, if the page fits 3 images per row but the last row only has 2 images, these 2 images must be left aligned.
5. I am OK to change HTML structure but no JS. Width of page and whole container is unknown.

**Example 1**: The number of columns is 4 in this case. The images (blue) is left aligned within the gray container which is center of the page (yellow).

[image]

**Example 2**: When the screen width is smaller, the images wrapped down (therefore 3 columns in this case). But the image container is still center and all images are left aligned.

[image]

My current code only does left align but the `.center` class literally has no effect. Somehow I need that `.center` class (red border) to have the width of the images inside (not full width) and then centered itself.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
  <div class='center'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' />
        <div class='caption'>
          <h3>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus</h3>
          <p>Fusce dapibus tellus ac cursus commodo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' />
        <div class='caption'>
          <h3>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus</h3>
          <p>Fusce dapibus tellus ac cursus commodo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' />
        <div class='caption'>
          <h3>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus</h3>
          <p>Fusce dapibus tellus ac cursus commodo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' />
        <div class='caption'>
          <h3>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus</h3>
          <p>Fusce dapibus tellus ac cursus commodo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' />
        <div class='caption'>
          <h3>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus</h3>
          <p>Fusce dapibus tellus ac cursus commodo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' />
        <div class='caption'>
          <h3>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus</h3>
          <p>Fusce dapibus tellus ac cursus commodo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' />
        <div class='caption'>
          <h3>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus</h3>
          <p>Fusce dapibus tellus ac cursus commodo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col-md-12 {
    background: yellow;
}

.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
    text-align: left;
}

.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 215px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

**Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/Rp838/

Any help?

**UPDATE 1:**

Followed Matt's advise to "Wrap the whole thing in a .container". Still didn't work as you see the red border box is not center of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/Rp838/1/

[image]

Comment: get rid of the .center div. Wrap the whole thing in a .container and it will be a centred layout. If you don't want it full-width, add some left and right margins to the container

Comment: Please see my update 1. Didn't work.

Comment: I am looking at your fiddle and it looks like the .center class element is already centered?

Comment: @Lloyd please see my screenshot

Answer (score 2):

finally solved it after the entire morning of going through stuff.
here is the jsfiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rp838/9/

```
                    .menu {
              display: block;
              height: 100%;
              max-width: 1000px;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
              text-align: center;
              /*flex-direction: row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-around;*/
            }

            .menuItem {
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              margin: 0 5px 20px 5px;
              max-width: 320px;
            }

            .menuItem img {
              max-width: 100%;
            }

            .menuItem h2 {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              text-align: center;
              color: white;
              font: bold 1.5em/2em Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
              background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
              /* fallback color */

              background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            }

            .menuItem h3 {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              text-align: center;
              color: white;
              font: bold 1em/1.5em Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
              background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
              /* fallback color */

              background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            }

            .menu li {
              list-style: none;
            }

            .menu a {
              font-weight: normal;
              text-decoration: none;
            }

            .menu a:hover {
              text-decoration: underline;
            }

            .menu a:active {
              text-decoration: underline;
            }






                <div class="menu">
                <div class="menuItem">
                  <a href="history.html"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="History" />
                    <h2>History</h2>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuItem">
                  <a href="photographs.html"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Photographs" />
                    <h2>Photographs</h2>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuItem">
                  <a href="videos.html"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Videos" />
                    <h2>Videos</h2>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuItem">
                  <a href="documents.html"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Documents" />
                    <h2>Documents</h2>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuItem">
                  <a href="maps.html"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Maps" />
                    <h2>Maps</h2>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuItem">
                  <a href="biographies.html"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Biographies" />
                    <h2>Biographies</h2>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok here we go, you need to restructure your markup to follow bootstrap standards

CSS

```
.container {
    background: yellow;
}

.thumbnail {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cardeo/qQ4Vd/2/) if you want to see it in action. I made the images responsive so make sure you stretch out the window far enough. On a smaller viewport the image will stretch to fit.

Comment: Just update requirement (1) above. Basically I don't want to restrict to **X number of columns**. I forgot to mention a few things. The reasons I didn't use `.container` and `.row` in Bootstrap 3 is because I want it to be fluid width. Those two classes are not required as of v3. Then each thumb will be just `inline-block` and stay next to each other and roll down when reach width.

Comment: Well if you remove the .container and .row then it should work as is above. You still had errors in your original markup. Not sure why you wouldn't want to use .container. It's essentially the same as what you're doing with .grid. Seems overly complicated. If you don't want to use .row that would make sense in your use case

Comment: actually had to change a few other things. Above code should work for you now. Fiddle is also updated

Comment: New code uses `width:100%` but in my case the images have fixed width (no responsive). Just imagine the whole image grid must be center of the screen but within the grid, they are left aligned.

Comment: yes that should work. The .container will center the layout in the browser. If you want more left and right margin, just add it to the .container. The contents within are left-aligned. Drop it into an actual page to test it out. the fiddle can be a bit misleading. I removed the responsive image stuff. The width of each image and caption will be set by whatever the image width is

Comment: Thanks for a lot of helps here but the code still has issue and doesn't seem to match what I was looking for. Could you look at the two examples above again (screenshots)?

Comment: If you want the thumbs to hug the right edge of the container, you can't use a fluid grid, it has to be fixed. There will always be an in between width until the layout is wide enough for another thumb to come up into the row

Comment: Maybe I should slack the requirement and allow usage of JS here?

Comment: There's lots of masonry js plugins out there. It would probably work better for this use case